# How to select distinct result set in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table, sample data like this. There are names associated with multiple ids

```
Id Name
-------
1 A
1 B
2 A
2 B
```

Result needed

```
ID Name
--------
1 A
1 B
```

How to get this? Order of ID doesn't matter

Comment: `WHERE Id = 1`?

Comment: Please explain the logic for the result set.

Answer (score 1):

TL; DR

```sql
SELECT min(id) as id, name from mytable GROUP BY name
```

When you need to summarize over multiple records in SQL, each column you include should either be aggregated using a function like min(), max() or sum(); or included in the GROUP BY clause. Here you are looking to pick an arbitrary ID, so why not use the "min()" ID? Then we want each unique name, so we add it to the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: A *good* answer would come with at least some text to explain what the answer is doing, not matter how simple to solution.